# How is one side of a magnetic material attracted to opposing poles of a magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism

Magnetic materials are commonly diamagnetic, paramagnetic or ferromagnetic. The following pdf (http://faculty.washington.edu/mrdepies/122/Workbook_122/WB_Solution_Ch32.pdf; see exercise #2) claims that magnetic materials are attracted to **either** pole of a magnet.

I understand that magnetic materials become magnetized when their domains are induced to spin in the same direction. The consistent spin somehow gives rise to a magnetic attraction.

How is it, however, that ***one* given side** of a magnetic object can attract to either side of a magnet. I would expect the magnetic material to behave as a magnet would and **have poles**.

Answer (score 2):

That is true for **paramagnetic** material only. On the contrary, diamagnetic ball will be repelled from both poles.
To see why, consider the potential energy of a magnetic moment $\boldsymbol\mu$ in an external magnetic field $\boldsymbol B$:
\begin{equation}
U = -\boldsymbol \mu \boldsymbol B. \tag{1}
\end{equation}
Now, notice that in linear approximation $\boldsymbol \mu = \chi\boldsymbol B$, where $\chi$ is positive or negative for a paramagnet or a diamagnet respectively. Substituting this into (1):
\begin{equation}
U = -\chi B^2. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
The force acting on the moment:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol F = -\nabla U = \chi \nabla(B^2). \tag{3}
\end{equation}
In the vicinity of any pole, the gradient of $B^2$ points towards the pole (denser field lines). Hence $\boldsymbol F$ points towards a pole for a paramagnet, and to outside for a diamagnet.

Obviously, a ferromagnet will be different because $\boldsymbol \mu \neq \chi\boldsymbol B$ in this case.